# Run Console application On server(IIS 7 & Windows Server 2003)

Tags: c#, iis-7, console

I Have Created a Console Application Using C# .net and it's working fine on my local system but when i am copying bin folder to Server and running .exe file noting happens(a black screen Comes and Disappear in a second) I have checked on Sql Server Profiler Everything working fine I Have Used Try Catch Block to check exception but nothing works ..... 
my Code is

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get All User
            var userList = BLLMailAlert.GetAllSubscribedUser();
            // Send UserID as Parameter and Find Tenders For Users
            var InCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var fromEmail = string.Empty;
            var toEmail = string.Empty;
            foreach (var user in userList)
            {
                // For Each AlertId Find Template Name and EmailId
                var userDetail = BLLMailAlert.GetUserAllDetail(user.AlertID);
                var userTenders = BLLMailAlert.GetAllTenderForPaidUser(user.UserID).ToList();
                if (userTenders.Count > 0)
                {
                    // According to TemplatePath Send tender Alert to each user 
                    var TemplatePath = userDetail.UserTypeTemplate.EmailTemplatePath;
                    var HeaderTemplateForPaidUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HeaderTemplateForPaidUser"];
                    var FooterTemplateForPaidUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FooterTemplateForPaidUser"];
                    toEmail = userDetail.Email;
                    fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminMail"];
                    var sbMail = new StringBuilder();
                    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(HeaderTemplateForPaidUser))
                    {
                        sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                        sbMail.Replace("{Name}", userDetail.Name);
                        sbMail.Replace("{CurrentDate}", currentDate.ToString("D"));
                    }

                    foreach (var tender in userTenders)
                    {
                        using (var sReader = new StreamReader(TemplatePath))
                        {
                            sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                            sbMail.Replace("{TenderTitle}", tender.TenderTitle);
                            sbMail.Replace("{TenderID}", tender.TenderID.ToString("####"));
                            sbMail.Replace("{TenderType}", tender.TenderTypeName);
                            sbMail.Replace("{TenderValue}", tender.TenderValue.ToString("₹ 0,0", InCulture));
                            sbMail.Replace("{TenderEMD}", tender.TenderEMD);
                            sbMail.Replace("{Location}", tender.Location);
                            sbMail.Replace("{OrgName}", tender.OrgName);
                            sbMail.Replace("{LastDateForSubmission}", tender.LastDateForSubmission.ToString("d"));
                            sbMail.Replace("{SubProductCatName}", tender.SubProductCatName);
                            sbMail.Append("<br />");
                        }
                    }

                    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(FooterTemplateForPaidUser))
                    {
                        sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                    }

                    var mailReport = BLLMailAlert.SendTenderAlert(fromEmail, toEmail, sbMail.ToString());
                    if (mailReport)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Tender Alert Send " + currentDate);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter 1...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        // using (var writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
                        // {
                        // writer.WriteLine("Tender Alert Send" + currentDateTime);
                        // }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unable To Send Tender Alert" + currentDate);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter 2...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        // using (var writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
                        // {
                        // writer.WriteLine("Unable To Send Tender Alert" + currentDateTime);
                        // }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Tender Found" + currentDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter 3...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter 4...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have tried by Writting Console.WriteLine("Hey Vishal");
in main but it's still not working

Comment: Down Voters must also tell the reason......

Comment: Telling us "nothing works" and "not working" are not at all helpful. Clearly _something_ works as you get a window displayed, if only for a second. You need to add some trace messages to your code to help you narrow down where your code is failing. I suspect that you failed to copy something your program needs to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Use Console.ReadLine("some text") to read Exception messages as exception messages are coming on black screen but it disappears very early so i have used Console.ReadLine("some text") through which i was able to figure out what is wrong..........

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not working? When you run a console application by double clicking the .exe then it will exit when it finishes, unless you've told it to wait for something. What happens if you open a command window (cmd.exe) and run your application by the command line instead - that way the command window will stay open and you can see any console output before you close it.

Does this run on your server?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: as from code you can see i have written Console.WriteLine("Unable To Send Tender Alert" + currentDate);
 Console.WriteLine("No Tender Found" + currentDate);
Console.Write(ex);  In case code doesn't execute Properly it should show messages.....